# C# Extension Method Return Value Not Setting Variable

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Why doesn't this extension method set the value it's applied to?

```
public static byte ExtSetBits(this byte original, byte value, byte bitSize)
{
    unchecked { original &= (byte)~bitSize; }
    original |= (byte)(value & bitSize);
    return original;
}
```

This is the call ( selectedIndex = 13 ):

```
byte test = 0xFF;
test.ExtSetBits(selectedIndex, 0x1F);
Console.WriteLine("test:" + test.ToString("X").PadLeft(2,'0'));
```

Writes "test: FF" to the console.

If I do this it works:

```
byte test = 0xFF;
test = test.ExtSetBits(selectedIndex, 0x1F);
Console.WriteLine("test:" + test.ToString("X").PadLeft(2,'0'));
```

Writes "test: ED" to the console.  I shouldn't have to reassign the variable right?  I've written many other extensions.

Comment: read about value types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes - you're not *using* the return value of the method in your first snippet. All you need is to set the return value, just as you're doing in the working case (your second code snippet). Changing the value of the *parameter* makes no difference, because it's a by-value parameter. The fact that you're using an extension method is irrelevant here.

Imagine your code was *actually* just:

```
ExtensionClass.ExtSetBits(test, selectedIndex, 0x1F);
```

After all, that's what the compiler is converting your code to. If you ignore the fact that it's an extension method (which you should, as it's irrelevant here) would you expect that to change the value of `test`? To do that, you'd need to pass it by reference (with `ref`) - but an extension method's first parameter isn't allowed to have the `ref` modifier.

You might want to read [my article about parameter passing](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html) for a bit more background, along with [my article about value types and reference types](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html).

Comment: Well if that's the case, then I'm REALLY confused as this appears to work well. public static byte[] ExtSetBit(this byte[] bytes, int bit, bool value)
        {
            BitArray ba = new BitArray(bytes);
            ba.Set(bit, value);
            ba.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
            return bytes;
        }

Comment: Call looks like this:cpnForceLB.Data.LightbarData.FunctionsOn.ExtSetBit(bit, btn.BackColor == Color.Lime);

Comment: @StevenDavis: That's not changing the value of `bytes`. (There's no statement of `bytes = ...`.) It's changing data within the object that the value of `bytes` refers to. I suggest you put down extension methods for the moment, and revise core C#.

Comment: Very well.  Tapping out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`byte` is a value type. `test` and `original` are both distinct values, modifying one does not modify the other.

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying the value of the test in your function. The parameter is a copy of your variable, you are changing it's value and then returning it. If you want to manipulate the variable then you should use `ref` modifier but the first parameter of extension method can't be declared as `ref`.