# Multiple Overloaded Extension Methods in C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, asp.net-core

Having an issue setting data with an overloaded extension method -

I have two extension methods:

```
public static void Fill(this SearchRequest request, ISearchViewModel vm)
{
    request.blabla = vm.blabla;
}

public static void Fill(this IEnumerable<IViewModel> response, SearchResponse searchResponse)
{
 // a list is created here and assigned to response
  List<IViewModel> someResults = new List<IViewModel>();
 // do stuff with search response and someResults
 response = someResults;
}
```

I first call:

```
 SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest ();
 request.Fill(criteria);
```

and request.blabla gets set as expected. So far so good.

I then try:

```
ResultViewModel result = new ResultViewModel ();
result.searchResult.Fill(searchResponse);
```

.searchResult is an IEnumerable of IViewModel, but after the Fill line is called, the result.searchResult is null. The fill extension method is definitely being called, and is definitely setting data.

Any ideas on what may be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

(I'm using VS 2015 and this is a vNext project - and no those are not real variable / class names)

Comment: I suggest you use *real* code that you've compiled.  A short and self-contained example with a `Main` method would be ideal.

Comment: The second extension method's parameters has repeated **response**. Put the code you use to assign to response(first param)

Comment: When you say something isn't working, let us see that. With the posted pseudo code, we can't help easily. Post the actual code which doesn't work. Or at least code alike which doesn't work(MVCE).

Comment: @rejnev - I've updated the question, sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @Azat - I've updated the code a little. result is definitely defined. I've also tried setting result.searchResult to a new empty list before calling Fill. It comes back empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Extension Method Return Value Not Setting Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289093/c-sharp-extension-method-return-value-not-setting-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response` is the *value* of `result.searchResult`, it is not an alias to that *variable*.  Setting a value to `response` doesn't mutate `result.searchResult`.  There is no way to write an extension method that passes its implicit parameter by reference instead of by value.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and worked. I figured it would work the same way as the first method regardless of it being a property.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerables are immutable. Maybe you can change the type to something that is mutable like a List?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however using a list did not work. It was also null. Servy's answer above explains it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead of your code:

```
void Main()
{
    var f=new Foo();
    f.FillMyList();
}

public class Foo
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}

public static class extensions
{
    public static void FillMyList(this Foo f)
    {
        f.MyList=new List<string>();
        f.MyList.Add("some item");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have something similar now.